# Проблема в понимании рекурсии

Tags: python, рекурсия

Попрошу немного подсказок или алгоритм в идеале шаги как решить эту задачу, спасибо

Даны целые числа `n`, `k`. (`n>=k>=0`).
Вычислить
[image]

Comment: А рекурсию обязательно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основа рекурсии - пошаговое уменьшение размера задачи.
Рекурсивный алгоритм состоит из двух частей:

- Тривиальный случай
- Рекурсивный спуск

Рассмотрим тривиальные случаи нашей задачи:

- `k == 0`, тогда выражение обращается в `n!/n! = 1`
  Основной выход из рекурсии, в принципе его одного достаточно
- `k == n`, выражение => `n!/k!`, при равных k и n, `result = 1`
  необязательно, но хорошо оптимизирует этот случай
- `n < 2`, `n!` = 1, k по условию не больше n, `result = 1`
  лишний, k обращается в 0, раньше чем n
- `k == 1`, `result = n / 1 = n`
  лишний пункт, естественным образом разрешится в k == 0 на следующей итерации

Далее рассмотрим спуск:

На каждом шаге будем уменьшать задачу по обоим аргументам.
Для этого результат меньшей задачи `F(n-1, k-1)` мы будем:

- умножать на n, согласно факториалу в числителе.
- делить на k, согласно факториалу в знаменателе.

```
def foo(n, k):
    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return 1

    return n * foo(n - 1, k - 1) // k

# Нарисуем треугольник Паскаля :)
N = 30
pad = 8
for k in range(N):
    for n in range(k, N):
        print(f'{foo(n, k):{pad}}', end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

указанную функцию можно расписать следующим образом

```
n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)/k! = 
= (n-0)(n-1)(n-2)...(n-(k-1))/k =
= [(n-0)/1] * [(n-1)/2] * ... * [(n-(k-1))/k]
```

отсюда вытекает следующий алгоритм - для для заданного `n` и `k` надо считать член

```
(n-(k-1))/k
```

и умножать на результат функции для `n` и `k - 1`

при этом для `k = 0` результат функции равен `1`, отсюда код:

```
def calc(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        return 1

    return calc(n, k - 1) * (n - k + 1) // k
```

ну или

```
def calc(n, k):
    return 1 if k == 0 else calc(n, k - 1) * (n - k + 1) // k
```